# Appium java-client 3.3.0 doesnt want to start

Tags: scala, selenium, updates, appium

After update to java-client 3.3.0, my tests dont want to start. My Appium is in version 1.4.16.1 (latest).

my capabilities:

```
def setupTest: AndroidDriver[AndroidElement] = {
  val caps: DesiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities
  caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "")
  caps.setCapability("platformName", Setting.platformName)
  caps.setCapability("deviceName", Setting.deviceName)
  caps.setCapability("platformVersion", Setting.androidVersion.toString)
  caps.setCapability("appActivity", Setting.appActivity)
  caps.setCapability("app", Setting.pathToApp)
  caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true)
  caps.setCapability("resetKeyboard", false)
  caps.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 600)
  new AndroidDriver(new URL(Setting.urlToServer), caps)
}
```

my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it cant be compiled. Console log:

```
[INFO] C:\Users\medek\workspace\AndroidAppiumTests\src\main\java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] C:\Users\medek\workspace\AndroidAppiumTests\src\main\scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 52 source files to C:\Users\medek\workspace\AndroidAppiumTests\target\classes at 1450269109670
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient not found - continuing with a stub.
[ERROR] error: Unable to locate class corresponding to inner class entry for Factory in owner org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient
[ERROR] error: Unable to locate class corresponding to inner class entry for Builder in owner org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService
[WARNING] 8 warnings found
[ERROR] two errors found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did not found any solution here or in Google. If I try to downgrade to java-client 3.2.0 everything works well. But in official documentation I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little bit tricky. I tried to modify java-client dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and remove all Selenium dependencies. But one of my dependency was my second project, which has Selenium dependecy too. In this second project was old version of Selenium (2.42.2). So these two projects cant work together. After updating second project to Selenium 2.48.2 (LATEST), everything seems to work fine.